# Big->little (little->big) endian conversion of std::vector of structs

Tags: c++, stl, endianness

How can I perform endian conversion on vector of structs?

For example:

```
struct TestStruct
{
   int nSomeNumber;
   char sSomeString[512];
};

std::vector<TestStruct> vTestVector;
```

I know how to swap int values, but how to swap a whole vector of custom structs?

Comment: If I understand your struct, the only field that needs endian swapping is the nSomeNumber. So just loop around the vector like you normally would and swap just the int field. The char array field would be the same on both endians.

Comment: You loop over vector's elements and apply endianness conversion to every struct in the vector. Or what is your question?

Comment: If `nSomeNumber` is supposed to go over the network at some time, you should use a fixed-size integer type (something like `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`) as the size of `int` is **not** guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending that vectors via network. But now I see, that the problem is in different place in my code. The vector seems to be problematic before sending out. Anyways, thank you for answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments.  Endian swap each element in the vector:

```
auto iter = vTestVector.begin();
while( iter != vTestVector.end() )
{
    EndianSwap( iter->nSomeNumber );
    iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(TestStruct& s, vTestVector)
{
  SwapEndian(s.nSomeNumber);
}
```

Give or take, that'll do it. You don't need to affect the char string, just the numeric variable.
s.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a general way to do this (i.e. a single piece of template metaprogramming code that would let you iterate over the elements of a plain `struct`, recursing into sub-`struct`s and converting multibyte integer values whenever they are encountered) then you're out of luck.  Unfortunately you can't iterate over elements of an arbitrary `struct` in C++ -- so you'll need to write special-case code for each different type.